# How to show that an orbit of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ by map $x\mapsto x(2x+1)$ has order $2^{n-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

i´m faced with the following problem:

Let $n\geq 1$ and f: $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^\star \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^\star $ be given by $x\mapsto x(2x+1)$. Show that the directed graph induced by this map consists of exactly one cycle of order $2^{n-1}=N$.
We know that the cardinality of $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z})^\star$ is $2^{n-1}$, so i wanted to show that $(1,f(1),..,f^{N-1}(1))$ is a cycle with $f^i(1) \neq 1$ for $i<N$. I also found out that f is a bijection. I tried to find a rule to write $f^k(1)$ in terms of powers of 2, but now i´m stuck.
Every hint is appreciated, thanks!